# Correction of the if statement

Tags: javascript

It is necessary in the operator to compare whether the text contains the value "100" in the answer should be god = 10

```
function myFunctiontest566() {
 var god = 16;
 var test = "test 100 pups"
 if(test == "*100") {var god = 10;}
}
```

Comment: You are looking for `if (test.includes("100")) {var god = 10;}`

Comment: Also you'll not be updating the existing `god` variable if you redefine it within the if statement.

Comment: you need to use `.includes()` to check if a value is a substring of a string. also you want to make sure to not create a new variable named `god` but update the existing one .... 

`function myFunctiontest566() {
 var god = 16;
 var test = "test 100"
 if(test.includes('100')) { god = 10;}
 console.log(god)
 }`

Comment: The google apps script does not find the function: .includes() and .endsWith()

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`String#endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) and the value `100` for a check.

```js
function myFunctiontest566() {
    var god = 16,
        test = "test 100";

    if (test.endsWith("100")) {
        god = 10;
    } 
    console.log(god);
}

myFunctiontest566();
```